# Disable premultiplied alpha on Bitmap.compress

Tags: android, bitmap, alpha, premultiplied-alpha

I am saving images from my Android application with `myBitmaps.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)` which works pretty well, even with an alpha channel (The BitmapFormat is `ARGB_8888`). Then I want to read the images back into the Application, and remove the alpha channel, restoring a full opaque version.

This works everywhere the pixel is opaque enough. *But:* If a pixel is nearly transparent, strange artifacts occur: I guess it has something to do with this "premultiplied alpha", but have no clue on how to change this. Any idea on how to prevent these artifacts?